# Dates %within% Intervals

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Running into a real head-scratcher and not sure of how to resolve.  Really hoping some of you may be able to help. Also, first time I've ever contributed to StackOverflow....yay!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

start_date <- ymd("2014-06-28")
end_date <- ymd("2019-06-30")
PayPeriod_EndDate <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = '2 week')
PayPeriod_Interval <- int_diff(PayPeriod_EndDate)
```

This creates a vector of intervals, with each interval representing a pay period of two weeks in length. This is part one, and part one is relatively easy (though still took awhile to figure out, ha).

Part two contains a vector of dates.

```
Dates <- c("2014-07-08", "2018-10-20", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-06", "2018-11-30", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-23", "2019-03-15", "2018-10-02")
```

I want to identify *Dates* `%within%` *Intervals*, with the **output** being the interval that each date is within. So Date `"2014-07-08"` will be assigned `2014-06-28 UTC--2014-07-12 UTC`, since this dates is within this interval.

A very similar problem seems to have been explored here...`https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/658`

I have attempted the following

```
ymd(Dates) %within% PayPeriod_Interval
```

However, the result only calculates for the first element in the *Dates* vector.  I have since tried various combinations of for loops, mutating into factors, etc... with little progress.  This is work related so am really on a time-deficit and will be monitoring this post throughout the day and into the weekend.

Best and thank you!
James

Comment: Btw, the dataset contains 7.3 million rows of "Dates" and the vector of intervals contains 130 intervals.  Attempted map_chr briefly, but ran into a same length problem and abandoned the attempt.

Comment: Congratz on your first post! This is unclear "takes calculates". Also, could you clarify what your expected output should look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your question, if you have additional information!

Comment: Will edit of course, and the "takes calculates" statement is definitely unclear. Thank you for point it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tidyverse is very useful but sometimes, base R is all you need.  In this case the `cut` function is all you need.

```
library(lubridate)

start_date <- ymd("2014-06-28")
end_date <- ymd("2019-06-30")
PayPeriod_EndDate <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = '2 week')

Dates <- c("2014-07-08", "2018-10-20", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-13", "2018-12-06", "2018-11-30", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-23", "2019-03-15", "2018-10-02")


startperiod<-cut(as.Date(Dates), breaks=PayPeriod_EndDate)
endperiod<-as.Date(startperiod)+13
```

The output from the cut function is the start date of each pay period which the "Dates" variable is located.

Comment: This is extremely close to the solution!....I want the end date of the interval rather than the start date of the interval. I wonder if a str_extract would work, using the pattern result of the cut function, there is probably an easier solution.  I feel like this is the right process, and just need to tweak the code slightly...

Comment: You can convert the output back to a date object and add 13 days to it for the last date in the period. See edit above.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you So much Dave2e!

Comment: A brief update - the proposed solution worked brilliantly!  Ended up completing my part of the project exactly as the work day was drawing to a close.  It would not have happened without your help, it saved a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how a `map` - solution could look like:

```
map(ymd(Dates), ~ PayPeriod_Interval[.x %within% PayPeriod_Interval])
# [[1]]
# [1] 2014-06-28 UTC--2014-07-12 UTC
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2018-10-13 UTC--2018-10-27 UTC
# 
# ...
```

To have the result as a interval vector (and not list) you can use:

```
PayPeriod_Interval[map_int(ymd(Dates), ~ which(.x %within% PayPeriod_Interval))]

# [1] 2014-06-28 UTC--2014-07-12 UTC 2018-10-13 UTC--2018-10-27 UTC 2018-12-08 UTC--2018-12-22 UTC 2018-12-08 UTC--2018-12-22 UTC 2018-11-24 UTC--2018-12-08 UTC
# [6] 2018-11-24 UTC--2018-12-08 UTC 2019-01-05 UTC--2019-01-19 UTC 2019-01-19 UTC--2019-02-02 UTC 2019-03-02 UTC--2019-03-16 UTC 2018-09-29 UTC--2018-10-13 UTC
```

If you are just interested in the end date of the interval an option is

```
PayPeriod_EndDate[map_int(ymd(Dates), ~ which.min(.x > PayPeriod_EndDate))]
# [1] "2014-07-12" "2018-10-27" "2018-12-22" "2018-12-22" "2018-12-08" "2018-12-08" "2019-01-19" "2019-02-02" "2019-03-16" "2018-10-13"
```

`which.min` returns number of the entry of the first Date of `PayPeriod_EndDate` that is not smaller than the specific date in the Dates-vector, thus the Date which is at the end of the specific payment period.

Comment: I have not been able to replicate yet without throwing an error message

Comment: I guess Dave2e solved the issue for you - if you have trouble or need clarification, state the error message. It is always good to try solutions in a fresh R session with the same data you provided to us - this way you can see whether it is the solution which is causing the trouble or some issues in your original data / package environment etc...

Comment: I have not been able to replicate yet without throwing an error message.  I think Dave2e's response resolves the problem I was experiencing.  Thank you for putting the answer into map and map_int, as I prefer using map when possible, not sure why I was experiencing an error yet, but will work on it some more.  Thank you !!